# Are there military conflict open databases?

Tags: military

I want to make worldwide annual summary on military conflicts intensity.

Comment: You could create your own SPARQL query on Wikidata SPARQL Endpoint using these examples: [1](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Wikidata:SPARQL_query_service/queries/examples#Battles_per_year_per_country_last_80_years), [2](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Wikidata:SPARQL_query_service/queries/examples#Battles_per_year_per_continent_and_country_last_80_years_.28animated.29).

Comment: Thanks, that is quite what I wanted. I still wonder how complete are these data. There is nothing on Kongo in these examples, for instance.

Comment: Unfortunately, you are right, these data are very incomplete...

Comment: The list of references: http://dss.princeton.edu/cgi-bin/dataresources/newdataresources.cgi?term=47

Answer (score 3):

Have you looked at [The Correlates of War](http://www.correlatesofwar.org/data-sets/MIDs) project? Haven't used the dataset myself but I understand it's a project by a group of politician scientists collecting data on occurrences of war in recent history.

From the site description:

> Version 4 of the Militarized Interstate Dispute (MID) data collection
>   compiled by the Correlates of War Project provides information about
>   conflicts in which one or more states threaten, display, or use force
>   against one or more other states between 1816 and 2010. By definition,
>   “Militarized interstate disputes are united historical cases of
>   conflict in which the threat, display or use of military force short
>   of war by one member state is explicitly directed towards the
>   government, official representatives, official forces, property, or
>   territory of another state. Disputes are composed of incidents that
>   range in intensity from threats to use force to actual combat short of
>   war” (Jones et al. 1996: 163).

Answer (score 1):

You could look at the Armed Conflict Location & Event Data Project (ACLED).  ACLED is is a disaggregated data collection, analysis, and crisis mapping project.

It provides [data export](https://www.acleddata.com/data/) and a [dashboard](https://www.acleddata.com/dashboard/)

Terms of Use and Access policy begins:

> Non-Commercial Licenses - ACLED’s full dataset is available for use free of charge by noncommercial entities and organizations    (e.g., non-profit organizations, government agencies, academic institutions) using the data for non-commercial  purposes, subject to these  Terms of Use.   Non-commercial licenses may also be granted to for-profit media outlets or journalists citing ACLED’s content in    works of journalism; provided that such works are made available to the general public and benefit public discourse on the topic, subject to ACLED’s prior, written approval.

Full terms are https://www.acleddata.com/wp-content/uploads/dlm_uploads/2018/12/TermsofUseAttributionPolicy_4.2019-1.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative may be the [UCDP/PRIO Armed Conflict Dataset](https://www.prio.org/Data/Armed-Conflict/UCDP-PRIO/) and several related conflict datasets available from [Peace Research Institute Oslo (PRIO)](https://www.prio.org/Data/Armed-Conflict/).  The data can be viewed interactively from https://ucdp.uu.se/#/ and can be downloaded [here](https://ucdp.uu.se/downloads/).  There is also an [API](https://ucdp.uu.se/apidocs/)